# Publish Old customization of acumatica in 2022R2

Tags: acumatica

I publish customization in 2018R1. my customize is working properly but when I toke customization build and publish in 2022R2. When I publish I got error and cannot solve or knowing the problems of it. here is the error log

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: The error log you mention to reference is not posted. Also,  please ask a clear and direct question. "I cannot solve" doesn't provide enough context or details.

Answer (score 2):

Publishing an older version customization project is not necessarily a problem, but structural changes in Acumatica with each major version means a field you use in 2018 may be removed, renamed, or moved to a new DAC.  Often, these changes make older version customization projects incompatible with the newer Acumatica version.

When asking questions of this nature, it is important to include the stack trace.  However, not having any insight into your customization project, there is no basis to give any specific insight.

As your posted error indicates, the stack trace should indicate the nature of the error and where in the code to locate the problem.  "value cannot be null" typically either results from no record being returned (very possible when jumping so many major versions) or that the field being compared is null or being set to null when not nullable.